Auth.js/Next-authv5 The webpage at .../api/auth/callback/google.... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address
using the latest version of auth.js
For some reason I can't figure out, when I set up Google OAuth, I run into this issue when testing the integration:

Context:
I'm using the Prisma adapter to implement Google OAuth in my system:
src/lib/auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { Client } from "@/utils/prisma";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(Client),
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});

src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from "@/lib/auth";
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

I'm sure the .env file is set up correctly, and I've verified permissions in the Google console. I've also added myself as a test user in the Google console. When I click the sign-in button on my page, it redirects me to the Google account selector. However, after selecting my account, I encounter the error shown above. 
Any insights on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!
things i tried and failed to give useful information
first thing i tried

with some hope to fixing this, i went to the google console and checked all the permits it may or not need. The outcome was the same.

second thing i tried

Reading the full auth.js docs, and did not find anything really useful to use to solve this error.

third thing i tried and failed

tried to see the logs on the dev server, did not find anything useful, perhaps i did not get any error.

